# Having trouble writing the right algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to write a custom function to loop through an array list and compare the four sides of a quadrilaterals. Each side only needs to be compared 1 to 1 but I can't seem to be able to to figure out the correct way to loop through them. I drew up a diagram I attached bellow but I can't seem to implement the correct looping to do what I want to do. I made a simplified version of my Bounds class just for testing which uses a getSide(1-4) method to get the sides 1:North,2:East,3:South,4:West. For now I simply want to print the sides for my testing. i.e. (1 -> 11, 1 -> 11, 2 -> 8, 2 -> 12... ect.)

Edit: I forgot to mention the smallest numbers are the order I'm trying to get my algorithm to go through. Also maybe the tree is not as clear as I hoped, the lines are basiclicly going down comparing each side to of the quad to it's opposite. So the first sequence would be: Rectangle 1: 1 -> 7, then 1 -> 11, then move on to the eastern side and compare that to the west and so on until it goes through all for sides.

```
    /* Program I'm using to test my algorithm */
    public static void test()
    {
       BoundTest a,b,c,d,e,f;
       a = new BoundTest("Rectangle 1","A","B","C","D");
       b = new BoundTest("Rectangle 2","E","F","G","H");
       c = new BoundTest("Rectangle 3","I","J","K","L");

       ArrayList<BoundTest> x = new ArrayList();
       x.add(0,a);
       x.add(1,b);
       x.add(2,c);

       System.out.println(x.size());
       for(int i = 0; i <= (x.size() - 2); i++)
       {
          System.out.println(x.get(i).getName());
       }
    }


    /* Bounding Class */
    public class BoundTest 
    {
       private String north,east,south,west,name;

       public BoundTest(String name,String a,String b,String c,String d)
       { 
          this.name = "Name:" + name;
          this.north = "North:" + a;
          this.east = "East: " + b;
          this.south = "South:" + c;
          this.west = "West: " + d;
       }

       /* Get side */
       public String getSide(int a)
       {
          String returnName;

          switch(a)
          {
            case 1:
              returnName = this.north;
               break;
            case 2: 
               returnName = this.east;
               break;
            case 3: 
               returnName = this.south;
                break;
            case 4: 
               returnName = this.west;
                break;
           default:
               returnName = this.north;
               break;
         }
         return returnName;
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those things are rectangles and not quadrilaterals. Rectangles are supposed to have 2 sides equal. What exactly are you trying to do, compare sides of 2 quadrilaterals? To check what? Why are a,b,c,d Strings and not numbers?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here.  What do the trees correspond to?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't think of the name for them, but your right they're all quadrilateral shapes of varying sizes, or would be in the actual implementation. I updated my explanation too, hopefully it makes a little more sense.

Comment: Oh I get it. You start off with a side, which has a value, you then have to get the smallest value of the opposite side on any rectangle besides the one you start on. So with the first tree, he started with Rectangle A and a side of North. This means, he has to choose the smallest between the South sides of either rectangles B or C. He chose 7, the smaller, so now he has to pick from side North on either rectangle A or C. In this case, C is the only one left and it works.

Comment: The title of your question has very little information. Your code does not show an attempt at what to do, as far as I can tell. We're not going to write that code for you. Your trees are still unclear to me. Are they what you want to implement, or is this question also asking whether these trees are right? Why are there four trees, and how are they related?